# Vertica error code 3987 Multiple Decimal points

Tags: database, vertica

Has anyone any idea on this error code 3987 - Multiple Decimal points  coming from vertica . The doc doesn't say anything specific . Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't make sense out of this one. What were you doing when you got the error? Were you inserting something? What was the command? Can you also copy-paste the error message?

Comment: There is only 1 error 3987 in Vertica, which is documented here: https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ErrorCodes/SqlState-42V16.htm?Highlight=3987 , where it says that multiple primary keys in a table are not allowed. What could it be that you mean?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? This is a normal error while transforming dates using strings or ints

Comment: We were having a null date on a column of type date to which to_char was applied which was causing this error .